# What does config.set do in Karma?

Tags: javascript, configuration, karma-runner

What's the different between these two configuration files?

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../..',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  });
};
```

and

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.basePath = '../..';
  config.frameworks = ['jasmine'];
};
```

The second is shorter and more readable, but the first is used throughout the documentation. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Using `config.set` rather than writing individual assignments like in your second code snippet is a matter of convenience. It allows us to write a configuration without having to worry about inconsequential details of how Karma creates the initial configuration object.

#### Explanation

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/1e465b1f473212c208a34b81ad56e1b454deb7f7/lib/config.js#L270), you'll see the implementation of the `set` method to be:

```
  this.set = function (newConfig) {
    _.merge(config, newConfig, function (obj, src) {
      // Overwrite arrays to keep consistent with #283
      if (_.isArray(src)) {
        return src
      }
    })
  }
```

It uses Lodash's [`merge` method](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#merge). (Note that `merge` changed in Lodash 4.x and over. At the time of writing, Karma [restricts](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/1e465b1f473212c208a34b81ad56e1b454deb7f7/package.json#L311) the installation of Lodash it uses to be in the 3.x series.)

The `merge` method makes it so that when you call `config.set(otherConfig)` it combines intelligently the values of `config` and `otherConfig`. It is a matter of convenience. You could write `config.foo.bar = something` for each value if you wanted, but then you'd have to worry about whether the values you are setting already have defaults or not.

For instance, if I do this, I don't have to worry about whether `client` is already defined and what keys may exist on it:

```
config.set({
    client: {
        captureConsole: false,
    },
});
```

The net result is that I'm turning off `captureConsole` from its `true` default value, and the rest of the `client` configuration option stays to its default value. If I naively did this:

```
config.client = {
    captureConsole: false,
};
```

I'd be removing the other values that are set on `config.client` by default (e.g. `useIframe`, `clearContext`, etc.) Of course, I could do this:

```
config.client.captureConsole = false;
```

And it would work: the other values defined on `config.client` would remain intact. However, the default configuration object that Karma creates does not have values defined for all possible options that you can set. For instance, if I did:

```
config.customPreprocessors.babelModule = { ... };
```

I'd run into an error because there is no default value for `customPreprocessors`. I'd have to do this instead:

```
config.customPreprocessors = {
    babelModule: { ... },
};
```

Using `config.set` allows us to not worry about those details:

```
config.set({
    client: {
        captureConsole: false,
    },
    customPreprocessor: {
        babelModule: { ... },
    },
});
```